# How getValue except from attribut ID in EXT.Net Razor Engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ext.net

code in listeners bellow get value from ID #{CheckAll}, 
I want get value from other attribute.

```
@Html.X().ResourceManager()

@Html.X().Checkbox()
        .Name("CheckAll")
        .BoxLabel("CheckAll")
        .ID("CheckAll")
        .Checked(false)
        .Listeners(l => l.Change.Handler = @"var checkAll = #{CheckAll}.getValue();
        if(checkAll){            
            #{CheckAll2}.setValue(true);
        }");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your sample should work if you change `#{CheckAll}` to `App.CheckAll` and `#{CheckAll2}` to `App.CheckAll2`.

Hope this helps.